# Is it possible to create EC2, S3 bucket and assign inbound rules in a single script in AWSCLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket techino1bucket --region ap-south-1
```

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ******** \
    --instance-type t2.micro \
    --key-name ****
    --security-group-ids  *****
    --subnet-id *******
```

Now I'm using it separately. Is there any way to combine it so that if I run the script EC2 and S3 will be created.

Comment: Put everything in one function or bash script.

Comment: Ok, Let me try once again